# How to set variable before (debounced) method function in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I set `isLoading = true` **before** the function gets called? Right now `isLoading` is false until the debounced function is invoked..

```
<script>
import _ from 'lodash'
export default {
  data: {
     isLoading: false;
  }
  methods: {
    fetch: _.debounce(function() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      // fetch my data
      this.isLoading = false;
    }, 200)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are right, but I fixed it by setting `isLoading` in the watch property, which is triggering the fetch method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick I think:

```
methods: {
  fetch: _.debounce(function() {
    // fetch my data
    this.isLoading = false;
  }, 200),
  askForData: function() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.fetch();
  }
}
```

Now you call `askForData` whenever the need for new data arises -I guess for an user action-. This sets loading to true and calls `fetch`. Since `fetch` is debounced, any other immediate call to `fetch` won't fire another http request, but now the `loading` state is correctly handled.